# Typescript conditional type based on value of a field

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

**How do you strongly type your json when you have the following structure:**

```
{
 type:"A",
 query:[]  
}
```

**The above could be strongly typed in following manner:**

```
export class Schema {
    constructor() { }
    type: string;    
    query: []
}

create(schema:Schema){}// strongly typed json
```

But query property will always be array but the items could differ greatly.

**For example.**

```
If type == "typeA"

query property will have something like:
  query: ["","",""] //structure fixed for typeA

If type == "typeB"

query property will have something like:
  query: [{name:"",phone:1234}] //structure fixed for typeB

If type == "typeC"

query property will have something like:
  `query: ["",[{city:""}]]` //structure fixed for typeC
```

Answer (score 2):

Something [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgEQIZQwFQJ4AOcMA3gFAwz5ECCATnRnjALwwBEN7ANBVYXAAKAC3DE27AEI8+1OAGEAllGYT5MygHpNMDGAAmMCCBjgyAXzJlFYKHDoAzDMGKZs9Rs3KUVRAFzoWLgCAHRyHkwA3HwAjoj2eAF6eADaALoWVjZ2js6uQSJipHy+cAFuwURhAoVgcNGUcQkB3pQwYBjIZUZQdDYA5rxtMASidQHQfWD9fJaW1rb2Ti6B2EoqxT4C5UFy1UTreA0wTXSJm23AyuckHV0TvQPcMAA2IMBYiuAPU-2WlHMrKUYAApYxgCqsVYYCLMAA+0MOMARFVq9Ss2iocGgujocAwZAciDAwCgXzAMH6cCgAGUQF0oMIBgAKACUATB4EhrTxUEQdApJFKO2wezkaOepxud26AHIABJwF5vWXPUZiAKygDqIDoL30svMgJe1JgAA8OeDIWwqbT6dSmdM2dFFA4YMyzSFgSw2BUxQJDqyLqBICATSE3v0PSEpSEripWdFzEA)?

```
const enum DataType {
  TypeArray = "A",
  TypePhone = "B",
  TypeCity = "C",
  // and so on
}

interface DataArray {
  type: DataType.TypeArray;
  query: any[]
}

interface DataPhone {
  type: DataType.TypePhone;
  query: {
    name: string,
    phone: string
  }
}

interface DataCity {
  type: DataType.TypeCity;
  query: {
    city: {name: string, location: string}
  }
}

type JsonData = DataArray | DataCity | DataPhone;

// Test area
function getSomething(): JsonData {
  return {type: DataType.TypePhone, query: {name: 'Hello', phone: 'World'}}
}
let x: JsonData = getSomething();
if (x.type == DataType.TypeCity) {
  console.log(x.query.city);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public setSelectedValues(val: number | number[] | string | string[]): void {
```

Comment: um no. If the value of type is `typeA` then query will always be an array or `strings`. If it is `typeB` then query will be array of object that has this fixed structure/properties: `{name:"",phone:1234}`

Comment: I hear you, but afaik the closest you'll get is... export class Schema {
    constructor() { }
    type: string;    
    query: string[] | {name:string,phone:number}[]
} .. hopefully someone comes along and proves me wrong.